# Exclude favicon from clientCache section

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

Currently I have clientCache Web.config cache which caches all statis content:

```
<staticContent>
      <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode ="UseExpires"/>
</staticContent>
```

But I want to exclude favicon.ico from caching (or make it expiration date less). Is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `<location>` under `<configuration>` tag, specifying that it should be applied to that file only -- something like this (just an example -- **taken from real working configuration**, where favicon.ico has different expire time compared to all other files):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    ...
    <!-- your site config here -->
    ...
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="favicon.ico">
        <system.webServer>
            <staticContent>
                <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="366.00:00:00" />
            </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```